# how to debug error from stripe API call? need a node.js stacktrace across event emitter?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, stack-trace, eventemitter

I have a node webapp that makes various API calls to Stripe using the stripe npm package. Sometimes I get errors like the one below. Notice that the stacktrace is truncated so that I cannot see which stripe API call causes the error and I also cannot see where in my app this API call is made.

Is there anything I can do to get better error stacktraces?

```
Error: Missing required param: customer.
    at Function.generate (/home/molsson/dv/foobar/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:39:16)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/molsson/dv/foobar/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:175:33)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Note: the error itself is just an example. I have already fixed it. I just want to get better stacktraces or a better method of debugging these types of errors quickly.

I'm pretty sure my node version has async stacks by default:

```
$ node --version
v12.12.0
$ node -p process.versions.v8
7.7.299.13-node.12
```

I tried running with `NODE_OPTIONS='--trace-warnings --stack-trace-limit=9999'` but it didn't help.

Does it exists some kind of "async stacktraces across event emitters" debugging thing?

Comment: I don't see a truncated stack trace. Due to the way async operations occur in javascript, stacktraces in an error object are not always as helpful as they are in other environments.

Comment: True, but is there a way I get can the stacktrace pointing to where in my app the event message was dispatched from? Something like a "--print-stack-trace-for-all-event-dispatches" or similar. Or, is there some feature in the Stripe library that makes it easier to debug these kinds of issues (e.g. an environment variable that makes the stripe library not use an event emitter)? Or, if not what else can I do (other than switching from node to go or similar)? What if I randomly get one of these non-debuggable errors in prod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good answer to this question myself. The stripe library fires and event before making a new API request, so you can print a stacktrace from there:

```
    stripe.on('request', request => {
      const currentStack = (new Error()).stack.replace(/^Error/, '')
      console.log(`Making Stripe HTTP request to ${request.path}, callsite: ${currentStack}`)
    })
```

I added a STRIPE_API_TRACING option to my app that I can turn on if I experience errors without stacks. With the tracing on I can just scroll a bit up in the log and see what API calls was dispatched just before the error happened.